# SetWarnings Action not available in Access Macro

Tags: ms-access

Trying to create a macro that runs five make table queries. However, the SetWarnings action is not available which will enable me to turn off the query confirmation messages.

I tried to add it to an AutoExec macro but the option is still not available. The other thing MS SUpport site says to try the trust settings, but it is in a trusted location.

Not sure what else to check. Anyone else know how I can turn off the query confirmation messages?

Comment: In the `Design` ribbon do you only have `Action Catalog` selected in the `Show/Hide` group?  If so, click on `Show All Actions` and `SetWarnings` should become available.

Comment: Code that implements regular modification of database is usually not a good idea. And probably won't work if published as ACCDE. Why do you need to programmatically make tables?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not available' ?

Comment: Ryan - Thank you! That worked! Needed to select "Show All Actions".

Comment: Thanks for the responses!

Comment: The .accdb file is being used as an intermediary that enables a data connection between linked csv files and an Excel dashboard. In Access, a calculated columns are added in a make table query. The data connection only recognizes the data in the resulting table, but not in the linked csv files. Not sure if there's a better way to do it but it works.